# How would I design a clocked D latch from first principals

Tags: digital-logic

I would like to understand the design process for a Clocked D latch from first principals.  Is it the same for any combinatorial circuit: Truth table - Kmap the build?  Just i am having an issue with the feedback in this type of circuit.  It's really sequential, but it seems to me that all sequential designs using state tables always infer the use of a latch or more to store the state. I'm Kind of going round in circles with this one.  Every search I do always just shows the circuit and truth table which is fine but would like to design one from the ground up.  Can anyone help clear the mud?

Comment: Start with logical gates and `SR` flipflop. `D` is based on `SR`. Clocked `D` is based on `D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the world of sequential circuits, there are asynchronous state machines and synchronous state machines. A D flip-flop is an example of the former, and it is used to construct the latter.

The design of asynchronous state machines (combinatorial logic with feedback) is much more challenging than synchronous state machines. You need to account for all possible "race conditions" in order to make sure that you always end up in the correct state.

I'm not going to teach you how to design ASMs in general. That topic could fill a whole book, and there are many references available online.